# List of users with email and role

Tags: user-roles, users

I'm looking to create a list of all the users on my wordpress site with their email and role.

```
$blogusers = get_users();
// Array of WP_User objects.
foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {
    echo '<span>' . esc_html( $user->user_email ) . '</span>';
    echo '<span>' . esc_html( $user->roles ) . '</span>';
}
```

This function is sort of what I am looking for but the user role displays as an array.  Any thoughts on an easier way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the correct way to get what you need. Though I'm not sure why WordPress returns an array of roles since ( to my knowledge ) you can only have 1 role at a time. Roles being an array you can modify by just retrieving the role index 0:

```
$blogusers = get_users();
// Array of WP_User objects.
foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {
    echo '<span>' . esc_html( $user->user_email ) . '</span>';
    echo '<span>' . esc_html( $user->roles[0] ) . '</span>';
}
```

Comment: "you can only have 1 role at a time"... you can have more than 1 role at a time :)